# Where are the NPC settlements and vendors?

Tags: fallout-4

Are there any NPC settlements that have vendors where you can sell your loot, buy stuff, and get healed up? In the other Fallout games it seems like you found these right away, but I can't find them in this game. One of the loading screen tooltips says that most of the settlements have doctors that can heal radiation and crippled limbs, but I can't find these - I can just find the empty settlement locations that you have to build on. Where is the first NPC settlement that you get to?

Answer (score 6):

Here are some merchants you can sell stuff to:

[Abernathy Farm](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Abernathy_farm) - Connie
[Drumline Diner](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Drumlin_Diner) - Trudy
[Diamond City](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Diamond_City) - Major hub/Many vendors
[Good Neighbor](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Goodneighbor) - Minor hub/a few vendors
Grey Garden - Supervisor Green
Bunker Hill - Minor hub/a few vendors

Also vendors will visit your settlements (such as sanctuary) on occasion.

You will get a marker for Diamond City relatively early on during the quest:

> When Freedom Calls

Comment: You can also get a marker for Diamond City without questing by talking to the roving trader Trashcan Carla, or presumably any other roving trader who frequents Diamond City...

Comment: +1, that's a useful list, but the asker also mentioned doctors. Not all of those locations have doctors. Diamond City does.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to z''s list, there's also Covenant, Bunker Hill and The Slog.
Once you can build in a settlement, one of the stores you can make is a clinic. Build this and assign a worker, they become the local doctor, even when not at the store.